# Ubuntu gets frozen when turn on second screen

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have a desktop computer with GPU GeForce 1050 with one HDMI and one Display Port. I want to connect my screens each to each port so that one will be showing a desktop, and other will be an extension of the desktop. I used to use mini-DP for the second display and everything works ok. Since recently the problem appeared: whenever the screen connected via DP is on, the system gets frozen. I checked the processes and it shows that with DP-connected screen on, nvidia-modeset starts consuming all the CPU resources. As soon as the screen is off, everything works ok.

I re-installed drives few times (new and old), purchased a new DP cable (as was suggested in one of the forums) - nothing helps. Yet, the screen itself works perfectly if I connect it via HDMI. I also tried to use HDMI splitter, but I could not manage to setup extended desktop, only duplicated view.

Any suggestions how to solve the problem and have two screens working as one desktop?

Thanks a lot.

Addition: I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Mate desktop. Nvidia drivers 384.111.

UPD: nvidia-smi -a shows "Power Draw: Unknown Error"

Comment: 1) Unplug DP-screen and Open a terminal session and run `dmesg`; 2) Plug DP-screen; 3) Run `dmesg`again and read the output. Maybe some useful information will be shown there.

Comment: @Redbob, thank you for the recommendation. I have tried that, but no difference in the dmesg output. However, I have found out that OS does not get frozen (I can still connect by ssh and it works), but rather all the input devices (mouse and keyboard) stop to respond when I make the DP-connected screen on. Re-plugging them did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like after long time I found an answer: apparently the problem was in mismatch between mate and nvidia drivers. When I re-installed drivers of version 4** it started to work perfectly with both display and mini-display ports.